# Are the directions arrows / icons available In the Navigate SDK for Flutter?

Tags: flutter, here-api

I am looking for the directions icons, like turn right, turn left, third exit in the roundabout, second lane etc...
I am using the Flutter navigate SDK 4.7.0
Are those available in the SDK and if yes any guidance how to access them?

Answer (score 0):

They are not available as part of the HERE SDK directly, but there are numerous other places. For example HERE offers the MSDKUI open source project which offers direction icons like arrows, maneuver icons and so on.

- iOS format: https://github.com/heremaps/msdkui-ios/tree/master/MSDKUI/Assets
- Android format: https://github.com/heremaps/msdkui-android/tree/master/MSDKUIKit/MSDKUILib/src/main/res/drawable